# How to Configure Eclipse to Work with `ehcache`

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, ehcache

**Summary/Question**

I've rolled onto a project that uses `ehcache`. The project is maven enabled and when I run `mvn clean install` from cli all ends well.

The project can also be opened in NetBeans and everything displays properly, however when I open the project in eclipse, I'm seeing some errors related to `ehcache`. In NetBeans the spring-cache.xml is located under a "Web Pages" folder. This made me think that the eclipse project may not be recognized as a dynamic web project, however following the directions here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-project-to-web-project-in-eclipse/ I was able to verify that the project is indeed setup to support Dynamic Web Module, Java and JavaScript.

I also opened the project in IntelliJ and also did not see any issues with the spring-cache.xml.

I also didn't find documentation related to this version of ehcache on http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/ but the fact that things work in NetBeans, IntelliJ and via `mvn clean install` make me think its my eclipse setup. Thoughts?

**More Details:**

The errors I see in eclipse are:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ehcache:annotation-driven'.
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd, because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

[image]

And

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ehcache:config'.
```

[image]

My maven dependency looks like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which matches what it should be, based on: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations/ehcache-spring-annotations/1.2.0

My spring-cache.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring 
                http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

    <ehcache:annotation-driven />
    <ehcache:config cache-manager="cacheManager">
        <ehcache:evict-expired-elements interval="60" />
    </ehcache:config>
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation"  value="${ehcache.config.location}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like current versions of NetBeans and IntelliJ aren't as strict on checking things as eclipse is. :) The following is what I found out.

From [ehcache with Spring. google code xsd file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191081/ehcache-with-spring-google-code-xsd-file-not-found) I found out that the top error was related to the fact that the xsd is no longer hosted at the url provided.

Doing some googles, I found a reference to the version on github at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agentgt/ehcache-spring-annotations/master/core/src/main/resources/com/googlecode/ehcache/annotations/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd by changing my bottom xsi schemalocation to the above url, it resolved the issue in eclipse.

The stack overflow questions referenced, also provides a link to the google code archive of: https://code.google.com/archive/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/source/default/source

If you download the zip, you can then find the offical xsd in the zip at: `/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd` (it also has `ehcache-spring-1.0.xsd` and `ehcache-spring1.1.xsd` in case anyone else has issues with even earlier versions).

I found a way to reference the local schema file here: [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253402/how-to-reference-a-local-xml-schema-file-correctly)

I'm going to post a question on how to reference it from a relative path of the project, as we have both windows and mac developers on this project. If this is of use to you, the details will be here: [How to Reference Local XSD File By Relative Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106799/how-to-reference-local-xsd-file-by-relative-path)

Answer (score 0):

Summary of issue:

xsi-schemaLocation reference:

http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd

results in validation-issues in eclipse, on commandline maven there are no issues.

replacing the ref with:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agentgt/ehcache-spring-annotations/master/core/src/main/resources/com/googlecode/ehcache/annotations/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd

solves issue in eclipse. In maven the  saxparser will complain however if you 're not connected to internet.
By putting a proxy ref :
-Dhttp.proxyHost=[proxyhost] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[proxyport] -Dhttps.proxyHost=[proxyhost] -Dhttps.proxyPort=[proxyport]
the maven build succeeds....

I investigated this difference in behaviour:
in the ehcache-spring jar, ehcache-spring-annotations-1.1.2.jar, 
a META-INF/spring.schemas file is present.

Content of that file:

`http\://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.0.xsd=com/googlecode/ehcache/annotations/ehcache-spring-1.0.xsd
http\://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd=com/googlecode/ehcache/annotations/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd`

cmdline maven uses this content (and finds the xsd in the jar).
eclipse does not.

Solution I used:
go to eclipse preferences,
 XML -> XML Catalog and add a new user entry:

Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agentgt/ehcache-spring-annotations/master/core/src/main/resources/com/googlecode/ehcache/annotations/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd

Key type: Public id

Key: http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd

Alternative web adress: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agentgt/ehcache-spring-annotations/master/core/src/main/resources/com/googlecode/ehcache/annotations/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd

Re-validating spring context files solved issues in my eclipse workspace.

I like this solution better because it is a shortcoming of eclipse which i solve with an eclipse-specific solution.