# How to Reference Local XSD File By Relative Path

Tags: java, xsd, ehcache, xsi

This is a follow up on [How to Configure Eclipse to Work with `ehcache`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091553/how-to-configure-eclipse-to-work-with-ehcache) and there is an example of absolute path in [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253402/how-to-reference-a-local-xml-schema-file-correctly)

Since the `xsd` file is not longer being hosted, I downloaded a copy of it from the archive. I've put the file in my resource directory and would like to reference it in my `xsi:schemaLocation` from a relative path of my project. We have both windows and mac developers, so an absolute path convention like `file:///c:/project/foo` won't work.

Another alternative to relative path would be if there is a way to reference system properties for both windows and mac, then I could do 2 entries like `file:///$HOME/workspace/foo`.

My project on my mac exists in `~/workspace/foo` and echo of $HOME gives my home path.

My `spring-cache.xml` exists in `./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/`

My `ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd` exists in `./src/main/resources/`

The following are some that I've tried without success:

```
        file:///$HOME/workspace/foo/src/main/resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
        file:///./src/main/resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd             
        file:///../../../../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
        file:///../../../../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
        ../../../../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
        file://../../../../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
        file://$HOME/workspace/foo/src/main/resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
        file://./src/main/resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd              
        file://../../../../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
```

I also seem to have issues getting it to reference the file from absolute path too, so perhaps there is a different way to reference the file on mac? e.g. The following did not work:

```
file:///Users/me/workspace/foo/src/main/resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
file:////Users/me/workspace/foo/src/main/resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
file://Users/me/workspace/foo/src/main/resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
```

Answer (score 4):

Think my issue was that the webapp dir may not have visibility to the resources folder.

I say this because based on the reading of the following stack overflow questions, it looks like the relative path stuff should be pretty straigh forward: [XML File with local copy of XML Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053529/xml-file-with-local-copy-of-xml-schema) and [How to use Schema that is on local machine in XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856455/how-to-use-schema-that-is-on-local-machine-in-xml-document?rq=1)

I then tried to brute force the references, in case it was something with deploy directory or class path, and all of the following failed:

```
../../../../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
../../../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
../../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
../resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
./resources/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
../ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
./ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
```

**The solution:**

However by moving the xsd file from `./src/main/resources/` to `./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/` I was then able to reference it correctly/easily by just `ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd`